# C# Stop ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, datacontext

I have a `DataContext` in which I'm running an `.ExecuteQuery` to return some results.

I want to stop the query completely after a certain amount of time, or when a user stops it, but I have no idea how to do so.

I've tried to do some research on this, without and results.

```
using(SomeDataContext db = new SomeDataContext)
{
    db.CommandTimeout = 10; // Test purposes

    List<Something> sme = new List<Something>;

    // I want to be able to cancel this
    sme = db.ExecuteQuery<Something>("Stored Procedure that may take some time").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to scrap everything you have in LinqToSQL (which is a broken and unsupported tech) for EnityFramework. Then you can just use `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(String, CancellationToken, Object[])` you can use the cancellation token to ..well...cancel the query. Note. LinqToSQL does not support cancellation.

However you can also use ADO.Net DbCommand directly to do this. Its pretty easy.

```
public Task RunCommand(CancelationToken cancel)
{

    using(var connection = new DbConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            //setup the command
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancel.Token);
        }

    }
}

public void Main()
{
    var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
    RunCommand(cancel.Token);
    cancel.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach

Answer (score 1):

This is 2 different problems:

- To stop the excution of the Query after a set amount of time you could use the Connection timeout. Depending on Your database you could have a max run time for queries on the database.
- For the user to stop the execution is a bit more difficult. You would have to execute the Query async to Return controll to the user, but maintain a Reference to the Connection, then allow the user to Close the Connection. Depending on Your database, the database should register that no one is waiting for a reply and then stop executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this functionality by applying a logic.

Logic :

When you start **ExecuteQuery**, before that use **Transaction** and after successfully completing the execution **Commit** the Transaction.

Meanwhile If you want to *Stop executing the Procedure*. **Rollback** the **transaction** and **Close the Connection**.

**Risk : you have to make sure and test very well that it can maintain transactions and connections otherwise your database can go into **DeadLock***.*

refer Below sample Code and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

```
System.Data.Common.DbTransaction trans = null;
```

Declare at class scope.

```
//dbAdmin is my DataContext

dbAdmin.Connection.Open();
trans = dbAdmin.Connection.BeginTransaction();
dbAdmin.Transaction = trans;

 try
  {
   //Perform ExecuteQuery
    trans.Commit();
  }
 catch(Exception)
  {
   // Rollback transaction
   if (trans != null)
   trans.Rollback();
   return "Some error occured while saving record. Transaction has being rollbacked.";
  }
```

and in Stop Execute event,

```
 if (trans != null)
   trans.Rollback();
```

Comment: I don't think that rolling back the event will have a positive effect on what I'm doing

Comment: Why ? If execution is stopped then, I think, whatever changes are applied so far needs to be rollback.

Comment: See.. I have edited the answer.. now may be its clear to you.